# Quality of Brick, Modified 1 x 1 with Headlight over time

Tags: piece-information, quality

I have a problem with my [4070 Brick, Modified 1 x 1 with Headlight](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4070&idColor=1#T=C&C=1) [image: 4070 picture].

I packed my Lego and put in the basement at the end of previous century. Now I see my "headlight" bricks are broken at the bottom, or, if not visibly broken, they lost gripping strength. It applies to white, red, gray and blue. Actually, it applies to every color I have.

Are ones currently made more sturdy? Do they survive better? Or is replacing them only a temporary solution?

Comment: According to bricklink, some of these have a slot below the sideways stud. It's considered a defect rather than a design decision. Do your headlights have this slot? I think the general consensus is that the element has design flaws, but the element is considered to useful to retire it.

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve Either they does not, or I just don't understand what you (and bricklink) are talking about. I'll try to find a photo of this defect to see. If you can share a link to photo, I'll be grateful. Edit: you mean [this](https://img.brickowl.com/files/image_cache/larger/lego-dark-stone-gray-brick-1-x-1-with-headlight-and-slot-4070-30-531429-50.jpg)? If so, then no, they do not have it.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. Bricklink currently considers it as a different mold, but it's marked for deletion: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4070a

Comment: You can go on to LEGO.com for replacement pieces, or you can fix it with a little superglue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just got a call from LEGO Support. I can't repeat it word for word, but (translating to English) it was like:

> Over the last decade manufacturing process of this brick has undergone many improvements that have improved its durability. You shouldn't encounter any problems with new ones if you will buy them, and if you will have problems in two years after buy, we will replace them free of charge. Sadly, we can't replace parts older than 2 years for you for free.

Two years of play is quite a long time, so it seems they are pretty confident about quality now.